# Tkinter - show dialog with options and change password buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I use a python program called Thonny. Its used to make another box that said 'You have made it into the main application' inside but I removed that piece of text for now. I would like it to show a options button and a change password button. This is the code:

```
    import tkinter as tk

    class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.frame = FirstFrame(self)
            self.frame.pack()

        def change(self, frame):
            self.frame.pack_forget() # delete currrent 
            frame = frame(self)
            self.frame.pack() # make new frame

    class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

            master.title("Enter password")
            master.geometry("300x200")

            self.status = tk.Label(self, fg='red')
            self.status.pack()
            lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Enter password')
            lbl.pack()
            self.pwd = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
            self.pwd.pack()
            self.pwd.focus()
            self.pwd.bind('<Return>', self.check)
            btn = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.check)
            btn.pack()
            btn = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.quit)
            btn.pack()

        def check(self, event=None):
            if self.pwd.get() == 'password':
               self.master.change(SecondFrame)
            else:
                self.status.config(text="Wrong password")

   class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
            master.title("Main application")
            master.geometry("600x400")
        def options_button(self):
            def set_password(self):
                    e = tk.Entry(master, show="*", textvariable=self.password_set2)
                    e.pack()
                    but1 = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.password_set)
                    but1.pack()
            b = tk.Button(self, text="Set your password", command=self.set_password)
            b.pack()
            c = tk.Button(self, text="Options", command=self.options_button)
            c.pack()



    if __name__=="__main__":
        app=Mainframe()
        app.mainloop()
```

[This is What is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxZSC.png)
[This is what it originally did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOWnP.png)

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: and please fix the indentation as it stands we dont actually know what your proper code looks like as we have to move things around to guess what it could look like

Comment: so what is the question exactly?

Comment: The options button and the set password should appear but don't. Try it in python and see. I use thonny it works in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a little bit of a play around and I think this is what your after. I also changed your code a little bit as I always feel its best to put `self` infront of all widgets on multiclass applications.

```
import tkinter as tk

class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()

        master.title("Enter password")
        master.geometry("300x200")
        self.status = tk.Label(self, fg='red')
        self.status.pack()
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Enter password')
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.pwd = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.pwd.pack()
        self.pwd.focus()
        self.pwd.bind('<Return>', self.check)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.check)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.quit)
        self.btn.pack()

    def check(self, event=None):
      if self.pwd.get() == app.password:
        self.destroy() #destroy current window and open next
        self.app= SecondFrame(self.master)
      else:
        self.status.config(text="Wrong password")

class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):
#re organised a lot in here
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Main application")
        master.geometry("600x400")
        self.c = tk.Button(self, text="Options", command=self.options_button)
        self.c.pack()
        self.e = tk.Entry(self.master, show="*")
    def options_button(self):
        self.e.pack()
        self.but1 = tk.Button(self, text="Change password", command=self.set_password)
        self.but1.pack()
    def set_password(self):
        app.password=self.e.get()

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() #removed your mainframe class
    app=FirstFrame(root)
    #set an attribute of the application for the password
    #similar to a global variable
    app.password = "password"
    root.mainloop()
```

So with what I have done you get prompted for the password and if you get it right it goes to the next scree, then an options button appears and if it is clicked then an entry box appears allowing the user to change the password

Comment: Thank you! It works but The change password doesn't seem to change but thanks anyway!

Comment: it does, if you stick `print(app.password)` in the `set_password` function then you will see its changed, but because you are hard coding your password in the main method its gettting set to "password" each time you run it, to get around that you will need to store and update it externally

Comment: If this worked for you could I ask you to accept it as an answer then? As it would help me out a lot

Comment: I have another question, I have made another file and added a variable called password_store I would like this to be called up in the the place where the current password store is.

Comment: If your password_store is a text file or similar you can read it from the file but if it's another python file then you will need to import the value

Comment: Yeah thats what I did. I did `import passwordstore`

Comment: Doesn't Matter I got it working. Thanks For Everything,